# How do I update kodi-inputstream-adaptive on Raspbian Stretch?

Tags: kodi

I have Kodi running on Raspbian Stretch and one of my add-ons requires a more recent version of kodi-inputstream-adaptive. The repo is on 2.0.10 but the add-on requires 2.0.12 or newer.

What can I do to resolve this? I've tried to search extensively but I couldn't find a standalone ARM .deb for a more recent kodi-inputstream-adaptive and I wouldn't even know where to start with building from source.

Thank you!